# Pi4: Using two USB to ethernet adapters to connect to remote machines

Tags: networking, ethernet

I am trying to expand my Pi4's ethernet ports by using USB to Ethernet adapters to periodically connect and transfer files to two remote machines. I've been able to get a single connection working. However, when I plug in the second adapter and try to connect to the other machine, I get error.

```
$ ssh root@remote2 
$ ssh: connect to host remote2 port 22: No route to host
```

known

If I unplug the first adapter, I am then able to connect with no issue. Is there a workaround to this? Does each adapter need to be "mounted" in some way (analogous to USB, I don't know the correct terminology)?

Comment: Welcome earl! Are we sure we are talking about ethernet ports and not USB ports? If so post a link to the technical information on the board you have. You can use a switch on the ethernet port you have and connect as many other units as you like including the WWW. With this configuration you would enable sharing on the units you want to get information from.

Comment: What OS? Raspberry Pi OS does NOT have a root password. You can not use ssh as root.